# #1191 - Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list Error Coming When i am trying to do a full text search

Tags: mysql

I have a table.
The query of the table as follows

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `univ_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `content` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `content` (`content`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `content_2` (`content`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `title_2` (`title`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `title_3` (`title`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `title_4` (`title`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `content_3` (`content`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=36 ;
```

Has a title and content.
When i am trying to do a search.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('HAi')
```

It is giving expected result
When i am trying to do a search

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(content) AGAINST('HAi')
```

It is giving expected result 
But When i am trying to do a search like this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(title,content) AGAINST('HAi')
```

It is showing

```
#1191 - Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list
```

Comment: I tried ALTER TABLE <table> ADD FULLTEXT title(title,content); Not worked then i tried For every column then also the above error is coming out.

Comment: #1061 - Duplicate key name 'title' This error is coming out when i am trying to do above mentioned change.

Comment: Can you please add the create table statement?

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `univ_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `content` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `content` (`content`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `content_2` (`content`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `title_2` (`title`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `title_3` (`title`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `title_4` (`title`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `content_3` (`content`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=36 ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to recreate the table with the following statement:

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table` ( 
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  univ_id int(11) NOT NULL, 
  title varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
  content mediumtext NOT NULL, 
  date date NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id), 
  FULLTEXT KEY title1 (title),
  FULLTEXT KEY content (content),
  FULLTEXT KEY title (title, content)
   ) 
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=36
```

Then your `select`should running well.

Comment: Yes!.solved, the problem But in local it is ok But in remote i have a database of so much data What to do there?.

Comment: More clear how to excecute this query in remote `FULLTEXT KEY title (title, content)`

Comment: @Neenu Delete all indexes and create the new one.